# Easiest-by-hand way of recovering a generating set of a parametrically given space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I am given an $m+1$ dimensional subspace S of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the form

$$S(t_0 ... t_m ) =  \begin{pmatrix} a_{00} t_0 + a_{01} t_1 + ... a_{0m} t_m  \\ \vdots \\ a_{n0}t_0 + a_{n1}t_1  + .. a_{nm}t_m\end{pmatrix} $$

Where $t_0 .. t_m \in \mathbb{R} $ I want to recover a generating set for this. One hypothesis I had is that I can consider a basis, such as

$$ \begin{pmatrix} t_0 \\ \vdots \\ t_m \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} ... e_m $$

And evaluate then

$$ S(e_0) ,S(e_1) ... S(e_m)$$

Does that necessarily generate a basis for $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $m+1\le n$. You have $S=\{A\mathbf t\mid \mathbf t\in\mathbb R^{m+1}\}$, where $A$ is the coefficient matrix, so $S$ is simply the column space (image) of $A$, i.e., $S$ is spanned by the columns of $A$. You’re given that the dimension of $S$ is $m+1$, which means that $A$ has full rank, so its columns are linearly independent and thus form a basis for $S$. Note that the columns of $A$ are in fact the images $S(e_k)$ of the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^{m+1}$, so your idea was sound, but you don’t have to do any computations to extract a basis for $S$. You can read it directly from the coefficients $a_{ij}$.